# I want to add a gradation to the color of a circle with ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to add a gradation to the color of a circle with ARKit.
What should I do?

Like this, I can add a red color to the circle with ARKit.

```
let cylinderNode = SCNNode()
cylinderNode.geometry = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.5, height: 0.01)
cylinderNode.geometry!.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
```

Comment: What do you mean saying circle? I see just a cylinder in your code.

Comment: You can use gradient image of square dimension (i.e 512 x 512 pixel) and then set it as cylinderNode.geometry!.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named:"abc.jpg")